# The jar of this class file belongs to container 'RFT Libraries'

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, rft

I get this error when I try to integrate Selenium web driver with IBM RFT.

> The jar of this class file belongs to container 'RFT Libraries' which does not allow modifications to source attachment'

How do i overcome this issue? Can some one shed some light on it?

Comment: Hi Sona,
Please let me know in which src folder are you importing the selenium jar files?

Comment: Could you mention what steps one has to take to replicate the issue?